# How to order the resulting query information being inserting into a table while leaving existing table records on top?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to insert values from a table into another existing table and have just the values I am inserting be sorted in descending order based on a specific column while leaving the existing records at the top of the table. How do I do that? I have tried to use an Order By statement but whether I use the column name of the table I'm pulling from or the destination table's column name I get an error. Also this is being run in VBA using DoCmd.RunSQL.

Here is my existing query:

> INSERT INTO AllMetersAvgRSSI
>   (longitude,latitude,AvgRSSI)
>   Select
>   Prem.longitude, Prem.latitude,
>   DataByColl.[Avg RSSI]
>   From [Prem]
>   Left
>   Join DataByColl ON (Prem.meter_miu_id
>   = DataByColl.[MIU ID])
>   Order BY [AvgRSSI] desc

**Final Result**

I continued to fiddle with this and discovered than you can use an order by just like I have shown above to do exactly as I was trying to do. The problem I was apparently having was caused by the names of the column I wanted sorted being changed only from Avg RSSI to AvgRSSI. When I changed the destination table to have the same field name as the source table it orders the incoming information while leaving the existing information alone. I also did a test where I changed the name of the destination table to AverageRSSI and it worked the same way. So in the end it was the names of the fields being differed only by a space that was causing the problem. The final Query is:

> INSERT INTO AllMetersAvgRSSI
>   (longitude,latitude,[Avg RSSI])
>   Select
>   Prem.longitude, Prem.latitude,
>   DataByColl.[Avg RSSI]
>   From [Prem]
>   Left
>   Join DataByColl ON (Prem.meter_miu_id
>   = DataByColl.[MIU ID])
>   Order BY [Avg RSSI] desc

Comment: In standard SQL, table's don't *have* an order - the only time when an ORDER is defined is when you `SELECT` data. I can't remember how close Access is to this model, in this respect, but I'd generally advise that you ensure you have enough data present as columns in the table to support producing your desired output ORDER when `SELECT`ing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a temp table, add the first result set in the desired order. Insert your new values into the table, query the table to return your new results with an order by into your temp table, select your temp table the results will be in the order you added them unless you do another order by.

Don't forget to drop your temp table after displaying the results.

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be the answer. Unfortunately for me this type of answer has been happening a lot for me recently. I guess I need to stop wanting to do odd things in Access.

Answer (score 2):

Ordering in an `INSERT` makes no sense from a database standpoint. How the database puts the rows into a table depends on the underlying physical structure of the table, not the order in which they are inserted.

Maybe your application relies on an auto incrementing column being in a certain order which would then be dependent on the order of insertion, but if that's the case then I would say that you've made a mistake in your database design as there shouldn't be business logic designed around an auto incrementing column.

Remove the `ORDER BY` from your `INSERT` statement and if you need to retrieve rows in a particular order later then use an `ORDER BY` there.

Comment: You are making quite a few assumptions there. The end purpose of the table that these series of queries create is to export it to a .csv file at a specific file location to be used by another program. In order to make this process of gathering the data and getting it ready for use in the other program more automated and user friendly I am attempting to get the information together and sorted properly so the user doesn't have to go into each of the resulting files and format them individually.

Comment: Your export process should be handling the ordering of the rows in the export file if that's important, not a contrived ordering within the table. If you need some ordering column then calculate it during your insert rather than trying to insert the rows in a specific order.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You say to order the information by "calculate it during your insert" which is what I'm trying to do, order the information before it gets inserted into the new table.

Comment: Ordering the data as it comes in is very different from having a column that gives an order and calculating what that column's value should be. Again, tables DO NOT have an order. You may see a somewhat consistent order when selecting from a table based on the underlying architecture of the database engine that you happen to be using, but without an ORDER BY when you retrieve the data (not when you insert it) you can't be guaranteed of the order that you get. If you have to port to another RDBMS or upgrade Access you may find yourself thoroughly screwed when you get different results.

Comment: The order of the insert shouldn't matter at all.  Database tables have no order.  If you need to order the records for an export, do it at that time, and save yourself some frustration.  Tom H is spot on.